# Power Statistics in Ubuntu 14.04 shows me battery percentage = 0%. How to fix it?

Tags: power-management, shutdown, battery

in the past days I killed my netbook while booting, then I found that I can't turn it on unless it's connected to AC power.
Power statistics tells me the battery is charging, the time to full is 0, the time to empty is 0 and the battery percentage is 0 too. Even my Windows OS don't retrieve different values.

I don't have any experience with ubuntu, so I would appreciate if someone help me.

PD. English is not my fist language, please forgive any grammatical horror.

Comment: For wanywone who see this... the problem is on the battery: somehow, linux interact with battery mainboard while booting... when I killed it, I messed it up and I'm unable to fix this.